# External harddisks not recognized when switching on the harddisks 1 to 12 seconds after the PC, OK otherwise. Cause?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios

Attached to my Asus PC (running Win 8.1) is an USB case holding 4 hard disks (JBOD).

When I switch on the harddisks first, and then the PC, the hard disks are recognized.

When I switch on the PC first and the hard disks later, the hard disks are not seen (even when waiting for hours) - unless I wait for about 12 seconds to switch on the disks, then they *are* seen.

What does cause this behavior, is it a BIOS issue?

Comment: What happens when you just disconnect and reconnect the USB cable?

Comment: What are you saying?   That, if you boot your computer at 1:00:00, the hard disks are recognized if you turn them on before 1:00:00 or after 1:00:12, but not between 1:00:00 and 1:00:12?

Comment: @Scott, yes, exactly. If they are already turned on when the PC is switched on, the case's disk access LEDs are beginning to blink quite quickly, a matter of maybe 2 seconds. The PC is a fast Intel i7. If the case is turned on about 12 seconds after the PC, the LEDs begin to flash quite immediately. Turning it on anywhere between 1 and less than these 12 seconds: no hard disks available, no matter how long I wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A setting in the UEFI BIOS did the trick:

Boot / Fast Boot: Enabled.

Answer (score 0):

4 disk USB raids are always slow to start - What you are experiencing is normal.

Comment: No, what I mean is this: the hard disks will *never* be recognized, when they are switched on within the 12 seconds time window. I can wait for hours, they won't be seen. - Also, they are not organized as a RAID, but are simply JBOD.

Comment: Just have a timer that delays the computer coming on for 12 seconds to allow the discs sufficient time to be ready...

Comment: @Solar Mike can you explain how to 'have a timer' do the job for Herb, it could be a good detailed workable answer.

Comment: Don’t have time now, but something like this may work : https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/252926436362

Comment: @SolarMike, how does this explain the fact, that when I switch on the harddisks case and 1 second later the PC the hard disks *will* be seen. The PC quite immediately starts flashing the case's LEDs, nothing anywhere near these 12 seconds (its a fast i7).

Comment: @SolarMike, thanks for the link, it also hints at other quite interesting PCBs.

Comment: @Herb I wasn't trying to explain the issue for you - I was offering a possible solution... As for the recognising : it may be due to when the boot-up process checks for fixed drives which may not be the same as drives classed as removable...